# WDIO-Cucumber.js:Before and After tags should to run only once before and after all feature files or scenarios are run

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs

In my framework wdio-cucumber.js, I have multiple feature files. My requirement is that Before and After hooks should run only once after all feature files or scenarios got run, since WebDriver IO runs every feature file in a single session, I am not able to achieve my requirement. Is there any workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPrepare` and `onComplete` hooks of WDIO to achieve what you are looking for.

onPrepare  - Gets executed once before all workers get launched.
onComplete - Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit.

```
let status;

onPrepare() {
 status = 'Started';
}

onComplete() {
 status = 'Completed';
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio.conf.js#L183-L326

Comment: Thanks Raju, but in my framework i have some variables that i have to initalize so if i initalize them in onprepare and try to access or let's say print them in oncomplete , their value dosent show as expected.

Comment: I think you need to initialize them as global and use them inside hooks. You are trying to create in local scope and try to reassign them in global scope?

Comment: We are using Typescript in our framework , so how to create global variables in typescript .I have tried it but didn't find any working solution.

Comment: I am not so good with typescript. but I would suggest to create a variable outside both these hooks and try to reassign them inside these hooks.

Comment: added a pseudo code to help you understand it better.